# Contain a function within a query?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I have a query on a test database that relies on a function installed on that database. I need to run that query against another server that doesn't have that function and on which I can not install that function.

Are there any elegant and/or practical solutions to this? The function is quite complicated with a number of parameters and so I had hoped there was a syntax that would allow me to label off a section of my query as a function and then call that code from the main body of the query.

I have tried to Google but unfortunately, as you might imagine, the words involved just lead to articles on how to create functions.

Edit: I am limited to SQL Server 2000 functionality for this.

Comment: linked servers ? check this..[link](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/10/06/sql-server-executing-remote-stored-procedure-calling-stored-procedure-on-linked-server/) its for stored procedure.. Hope it will work in your case also..

Comment: I can't create a linked server as this would be a change to our production environment, and a link to our test environment would be a hard sell if I did try to do this. Thanks.

Comment: What I have so far is I've replaced the function calls with cursors.. not very elegant but I think I can at least make this work..

Comment: if i read things right, you want to be sure that your query runs good at your production db, syntactical in a way, without having the functionality of the function, but still with the call in it.. So you are looking for a stub kinda thing.. Well.. if you can't create anything on your target server, you are not able to do things. Maybe, and i don't think it'll work if i read your comments, you can use a tempdb functionality.. but i doubt it.. So as far as i know, it isn;t possible.....

Comment: Thanks I got around the problem eventually by containing the logic within a while loop and entering it for each iteration of the function I needed to process. Thought I'd posted back here as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best answer at the moment came from myself. I stored the data I needed to process in a #temporary table and then used a while loop with the logic required updating rows back in the #temporary table. Quite a bit of reworking, but it worked and as a run-once operation I'm fine with that.

Comment: // , Would you care to elaborate or provide a code example?

Comment: No @NathanBasanese, that was 2012 and I no longer have that database or code available to me :) As a one-off it sounds like something I'd use SQLPrompt for these days.

Comment: // , Hm. Could you show an example of the SQLPrompt, or maybe drop us a link? My database-fu is preeeeettty rusty

Comment: SQLPrompt is a 3rd party addon to SSMS. One of the fun things it allows is you can highlight a data set in the results window, right click it and ask SQLPrompt to generate create and insert statements for a temp table. Allow you to "move the data" or play with it in a new query. I think back then I did something similar by hand (export to CSV, Import Data into a table to work on etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You can't just create an inline function?  The create function fails as you don't have authority?   You might be able to substitute a CTE.

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_Test ( @sID nvarchar(30) )
RETURNS table
AS
RETURN (
        SELECT sID, sParID 
        FROM docSVsys 
        WHERE sID = @sID
       )
GO
-- Example of calling the function for a specific region
SELECT *
FROM fn_Test(N'2')
GO
```

Comment: Wouldn't the sample you show try to create and store that function against the DB? I am not permitted to do that. As I understand it CTE is a modern feature and I'm limited to SQL2000, which I will make more clear in the question. Thankyou

Comment: Sorry, I don't know of a way out.

Comment: Could you replicate to a serve you have control of?

Comment: Didn't see your query a year ago, sorry. No I could not. I could not guarantee where this query was going to be run after I handed it off so it needed to be very portable.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this is possible in MSSQL 2000 but you might be able to create a function on tempdb and use it from there ..

In 2008 it seems to work. So if you have rights to do that on tempdb this is likely to work.

Comment: I can't create a function anywhere on the target server. Thankyou. I guess what I have in my mind is like a single C++ source file for a simple program whereby you have a main() and in the same text file you have functions you can call that are outside of the main().

Comment: Yah, I understood what you needed, I guess that you can, if your code structure allows you, to create a temp table and with a cursor to use sp_executesql, but that would invalidate the function model you have in mind.